# Is it possible to include a Mustache.js Template saved to a Static Resource within a VisualForce Page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources, include, mustache.js

My VisualForce page includes the following Mustache.js template code:

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <tr><td>{{LastName}}</td><td>{{FirstName}}</td><td>{{Phone}}</td></tr>
</script>
```

I'd like to move this to a Static Resouce, so I copied the template code to a text file called OverrideRemoteContactObjectMustache.mustache and uploaded it as a Static Resource called OverrideRemoteContactObjectMustache, which SFDC decided (fwiw) is an "application/octet-stream".

I then tried to include it like this:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.VF_OverrideRemoteContactObjectMustache}" id="template" html-type="x-tmpl-mustache" />
```

My JavaScript wants to reference this template using

```
template = jQuery('#template').html();
```

But SFDC won't allow me to specify the script Id using something like `html-id`.  So instead I tried using

```
template = jQuery("[id='template']).html();
```

... which didn't work.

Is there some way this can work?